# Getting the weather in current location from Latitude and Longitude in iPhone

Tags: ios, weather-api

I have current location Latitude`[17.382042000000000000]` and Longitude`[78.481727299999990000].`

Is there any way find out the weather based on these Latitude and Longitude?
Is there any third party free APIs for finding the weather based on these values?
Can any one provide me some guidelines or URLs for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following URL. Change  Latitude and Longitude based on your requirement.

http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML
/index.xml?query=17.3820420000000000006,78.48172729999999000

To get the current weather condition you can use the following API endpoint. The only thing you have to Generate API key from their site. - http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api

Here is the endpoint : 
http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/conditions/forecast/alert/q/17.382042000000000000,78.48172729999999000.json

Replace the API_KEY from you generated API key.

Comment: Thanks ...@Inoka..But there are no details like..."max-min temperature and weather condition..etc "

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I have updated it to get the whether condition too.

Comment: Wow...Thanks @Inoka....it's working.....is it free api.....is there any limits for this api...

Comment: I have signed up to get the api key. But i am not finding my generated API key once i login. Please help me find the generated API key in http://www.wunderground.com

Answer (score 4):

Also, I'd recommend to check [OpenWeatherMap API](http://openweathermap.org/API). You can use it for free and I think it can help you. For instance, in your case a URL might look like this:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=17.38&lon=78.48
```

It will return a data in JSON format. For more details please check the API documentation.

Comment: don't forget {API KEY} in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSDictionary*)getWeatherForLocation:(CLLocation*)location
{
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

 NSString *stringURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/yourAPIKey/geolookup/forecast10day/q/%f,%f.json",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude];

 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

 NSURLResponse * response = nil;
 NSError * error = nil;
 NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSDictionary *dictionary=[stringData objectFromJSONString];

 locationDic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dictionary valueForKey:@"location"]];
 NSLog(@"locations is %@",locationDic);

 return [dictionary valueForKey:@"forecast"];
}
```

you can directly use api by passing lat long as

http://api.wunderground.com/api/APPKey/geolookup/forecast10day/q/37.785834,-122.406417.json

Comment: ok, As my point of view no answer is selected that's why I asked you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few APIs available for this. Look at some of the other StackOverflow questions:

[Get weather by html5 geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464415/get-weather-by-html5-geolocation)

e.g. Weather bug has an API method that takes lat / long positions:

http://developer.weatherbug.com/docs/read/WeatherBug_API_JSON

I am sure there are many more. Just try a few and see which one works for you.

Comment: @Venki looks like it is free, with a 500 request rate limit per day.

Answer (score 0):

yahoo provides a weather service - on the iPhone you need to

```
1) get your longitude & latitude using CoreLocation
2) use

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+place+from+flickr.places+where+lat=%f+and+lon=%f

to get a woeid (WhereOnEarth ID)

1)use

    http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%@&u=c
```

to get your weather report

Comment: see also this link http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39414-google-weather-api-parse-xml.html

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Mundra......But it's not working for my Latitude and Longitude....see this URL...[url](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+place+from+flickr.places+where+lat=17.382042000000000000+and+lon=78.481727299999990000)

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Mundra......How can i pass my Latitude and Longitude to this----->URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@\"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=%@\", currentLocation];